# How to run dynamic queries in Informatica cloud mapping task?

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I am new in informatica cloud. I have list of queries ready in my table. Like below.

[image]

Now I want to take one by one query from this table which work as a source query and whatever results return which I need to load into target. All tables were already created in source and target.

I just need to copy the data based on dynamic queries which kept in my one of sql tables.

If anyone have any idea then please share your toughs with me. It great helps to me.

Answer (score 0):

The source connection will be the connector to your source database and the Source Type will be query. From there it depends how you are managing your variables. See [thread on Informatica Network](https://network.informatica.com/thread/75372) for links to multiple examples.

Comment: Scott, thank you for your input. I checked Infomatica network link. But In those cases there were only where condition was dynamic but in my case entire query should be dynamic so Is this possible to keep entire query as parameter in informatica cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Read the table like normally you would do in the cloud. Then pass each of the record into the sql transformation for execution. configure where the sql transformation has to execute and it will run the queries in the database you want.

Comment: SQL transformation only support store procedure and function only. No directly query run by SQL transformation in informatica cloud. Let me know if you have other idea.

Comment: yes. you should create a function which takes in 1 parameter. the parameter should be the query .

Comment: In my query dynamic columns. So function not supported for dynamic columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a SQL task to run dynamic SQL queries.

link to using SQL task approach: https://www.datastackpros.com/2019/12/informatica-cloud-incremental-load_14.html

Comment: link only answers are worthless if link breaks